# Core Plot - Creating a graph of increasing size based on realtime data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, core-plot

Ive done some searching and haven't found anyone attempting anything similar so I figured id ask around here. What I'm trying to do is basically create a graph that will get data every say 5 seconds and plot it. So far the best I've done is allow the user to pan around a static graph of a static plot.

I'm currently trying to get to the point where I can press one button and it will create a new point on the graph based on a steady time interval for the X axis, and a random number from 1 to 100 on the Y axis. How I'm trying to do this is below:

```
@synthesize scatterPlot = _scatterPlot;
@synthesize statusLabel, data, isPlotting;

CGFloat xCoord;

- (void)startPlot:(id)sender {

    if (isPlotting == FALSE) {
        xCoord = 0;
    }

    if (isPlotting == TRUE)
    {
        statusLabel.text = @"Starting Plot";

        xCoord += 5;
        [data addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(xCoord, (arc4random() % 100 + 1))]];

        self.scatterPlot = [[TUTSimpleScatterPlot alloc] initWithHostingView:_graphHostingView andData:data];
        [self.scatterPlot initialisePlot];

        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(startPlot:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    }
}

- (void)endPlot:(id)sender {
    statusLabel.text = @"Plotting Stopped";
    isPlotting = FALSE;
}
```

This is basically the core of how I'm trying to do the described task. The idea is that I press my 'start' button which calls **startPlot** and sets the **isPlotting** value to true, then i increment my xCoord value which will be the time by an arbitrary 5, for 5 seconds, then I generate and add my new point to my NSMutableArray array called **data**. After that I reinitialize my scatter plot and start a timer to sleep for 5 seconds and call the **startPlot** function again.

The problems I've been running into is that it either just doesnt update and I get a blank X and Y axis with no points. In any case there is something that I'm missing that I'm hoping someone knows and can help me out!

Thank You!
-Karoly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing is a real-time plot, almost like an oscilloscope right? Have you looked at the example app; specifically the Plot Gallery project in the Real Time Plot? That should be it, it's in the examples folder.

Look the `RealTimePlot` class (in the project tree, under the Plots group), basically what is being done is setting up a timer that calls the method `-(void)newData:(NSTimer *)theTimer` add a new point to the data array, redraw and move the `CPTPlotRange`s.

What version of CorePlot are you using?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, that sounds awesome, ill take a look at it today. I'll post back after I've looked at it. I'm using v1.0, just downloaded CorePlot last week.

Comment: Took a look through the RealTimePlot class files and they look like they'll be useful, specifically the newData function you mentioned. Thanks for the info!